# Using self-signed certificate with SSL pinning in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ssl

What i'm trying to do is connect to my api server that uses self-signed certificate. I want to devise a solution where the app itself has that certificate and use that certificate to validate the request. I'm using SSL pinning to pin my self-signed certificate with the app bundle. While testing i found that the connection gets cancelled when trying to connect to the server. The app can get the server certificate and local certificate data and compare them which works fine. But while trying to set SSL policies for the server trust. It always fails and returns **kSecTrustResultRecoverableTrustFailure** . The only other way would be to install the root certificate manually on the device, which is a bad UX and if possible i do not want that for my end users. I heard it can be done in Android but haven't found any solution for the ios counterpart. Below is my delegate function that handles the SSL pinning. Any help would be appreciated as, help reading such issues is very hard to find. I know that the issue is due to the self-signed certificate not being verified by any popular CA, but i'm searching for a way around that.

```
-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session didReceiveChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSURLCredential * _Nullable))completionHandler {

// Get remote certificate
SecTrustRef serverTrust = challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust;
SecCertificateRef certificate = SecTrustGetCertificateAtIndex(serverTrust, 0);

// Set SSL policies for domain name check
NSMutableArray *policies = [NSMutableArray array];
[policies addObject:(__bridge_transfer id)SecPolicyCreateSSL(true, (__bridge CFStringRef)challenge.protectionSpace.host)];
SecTrustSetPolicies(serverTrust, (__bridge CFArrayRef)policies);

// Evaluate server certificate
SecTrustResultType result;
SecTrustEvaluate(serverTrust, &result);
BOOL certificateIsValid = (result == kSecTrustResultUnspecified || result == kSecTrustResultProceed);

// Get local and remote cert data
NSData *remoteCertificateData = CFBridgingRelease(SecCertificateCopyData(certificate));
NSString *pathToCert = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"randomCertificate.com" ofType:@"cer"];
NSData *localCertificate = nil;
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:pathToCert]) {
    localCertificate = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:pathToCert];
} else {
    NSLog(@"Certificate does not exist in app");
}

// The pinnning check
if ([remoteCertificateData isEqualToData:localCertificate] && certificateIsValid) {
    NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:serverTrust];
    completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeUseCredential, credential);
} else {
    completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeCancelAuthenticationChallenge, NULL);
}}
```